# How to override the from address in new emails?

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to override the from address in new emails.

The line `oMail.SentOnBehalfOfName = "<redacted>@<redacted>.com"` takes care of this, but there are some accounts I don't want this for.

The macro works fine normally, but if I open an email template I get

> Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set

The debugger highlights the first line of the If statement.

```vb
Public Sub SetFromAddress(oMail As Outlook.MailItem)
    oMail.SentOnBehalfOfName = "<redacted>@<redacted>.com"
    ' Undo FromAddress overide for other accounts
    If InStr(1, oMail.SendUsingAccount, "<redacted>@<redacted>.com", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        oMail.SentOnBehalfOfName = "<redacted>@<redacted>.com"
    End If
End Sub
```

Full Code:

```
Dim WithEvents objInspectors As Outlook.Inspectors
Dim WithEvents objMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim WithEvents myOlExp As Outlook.Explorer

Private Sub Application_Startup()
   Initialize_handler
End Sub

Public Sub Initialize_handler()
   Set objInspectors = Application.Inspectors
   Set myOlExp = Application.ActiveExplorer
End Sub

Private Sub objInspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Inspector)
   If Inspector.CurrentItem.Class = olMail Then
       Set objMailItem = Inspector.CurrentItem
       If objMailItem.Sent = False Then
           Call SetFromAddress(objMailItem)
       End If
   End If
End Sub

'Uncomment the next 3 lines to enable Outlook 2013/2016/2019/365 Reading Pane Reply
Private Sub myOlExp_InlineResponse(ByVal objItem As Object)
   Call SetFromAddress(objItem)
End Sub

Public Sub SetFromAddress(oMail As Outlook.MailItem)
' Set your preferred default From address below.
' Exchange permissions determine if it is actually stamped
' as "Sent On Behalf Of" or "Sent As".
' The address is not properly updated for the InlineResponse
' feature in Outlook 2013/2016/365. This is only a visual bug.
oMail.SentOnBehalfOfName = "aaa@domain.com"

' Undo FromAddress overide for other accounts
   If InStr(1, oMail.SendUsingAccount, "bbb@domain.com", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    oMail.SentOnBehalfOfName = "bbb@domain.com"
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sendusingaccount  `SendUsingAccount` is an object-type property so maybe first test it's not `Nothing` before trying to access it

Comment: Thanks for such a fast response @TimWilliams, I don't think it's Nothing because as long as I dont use a template it works as I expect. Maybe email templates are handled differently because for example you can open a template without opening Outlook.

Comment: Are you trying to override the sender on the message that you have already received? But only when the user opens them?

Comment: Hi @DmitryStreblechenko, I'm trying to override the from address for new emails I'm sending or when I reply. I have an account with multiple aliases and Outlook defaults to the primary alias which I don't want to use in most cases because for example most of the mail I need to reply to is sent to another alias.

Comment: Override to something Outlook won't let you set manually? Or just automate the selection of a particular account already available in Outlook?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko, yes, just to avoid having to choose the address from the drop down list to save time and in case I forget. It's mainly the replies that are a problem because I receive an email at alias B and then if I'm not careful reply with alias A.

Comment: Just to clarify. The macro appears to work perfectly until I try to open an email template, at which point I get the error above and the macro crashes forcing me to restart Outlook. Also, when the template opens in a the new window, as usual when opening a template in Explorer, the address does get overridden by the macro before the macro crashes. I need the line that causes the crash because it reverts the overridden address on another account in Outlook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
If InStr(1, oMail.SendUsingAccount, "<redacted>@<redacted>.com", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
```

assumes that `oMail.SendUsingAccount` is set. Check to make sure it is not null (note that the `If` statement is split into two since VB Script does not short-circuit boolean statements)

```
if Not oMail.SendUsingAccount Is Nothing Then
  If InStr(1, oMail.SendUsingAccount.DisplayName, "<redacted>@<redacted>.com", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. 
I thought the line `Public Sub SetFromAddress(oMail As Outlook.MailItem)` was setting that.
If I try the following it makes no difference:

`Public Sub SetFromAddress()
Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
    If InStr(1, oMail.SendUsingAccount, "<redacted>@<redacted>.com", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        oMail.SentOnBehalfOfName = "<redacted>@<redacted>.com"
    End If
End Sub`

Comment: You are missing my point. Its is not that `oMail` is null, but rather its `SendUsingAccount` property. If it has never been set, it will be null. There is no default value. And your existing code causes VBA to retrieve the default `Account` object property, so you'd be better off expliiclty specifying the `Account.DisplayName` property - see the above.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to set both properties on new items - [SentOnBehalfOfName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sentonbehalfofname) and [SendUsingAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sendusingaccount). Instead, you need to choose one depending on your needs.

The `SendUsingAccount` property sets or gets an `Account` object that represents the account under which the `MailItem` is to be sent. That means the other account should be configured in Outlook.

The `SentOnBehalfOfName` property sets a string indicating the display name for the intended sender of the mail message. In that case you need to be sure you have sufficient privileges to send on behalf of another person.

But the following error message clearly indicates that you do not deal with a valid mail item:

> Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set

You can check the argument passed to the method. Please remember that Outlook folders may contain different kind of items. Sometimes makes sense check the message class to be sure you deal with a mail item.

Comment: Thanks Eugene, I really appreciate the quick and detailed response. Forgive me, but I don't really understand what you mean.

Comment: Thanks again Eugene, I see now that you were pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who finds this the full and apparently working script is here:

```
'================================================================================
'Description: Outlook macro to automatically set a different
'             From address.
'
'Comment: You can set the email address at the bottom of the code.
'         Uncomment the myOlExp_InlineResponse sub to also make it
'         work with the Reading Pane reply feature of Outlook 2013/2016/2019/365.
'
' author : Robert Sparnaaij (updated to include templates)
' version: 1.1 (1.2)
' website: https://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/setfromaddress.htm
'================================================================================

Dim WithEvents objInspectors As Outlook.Inspectors
Dim WithEvents objMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim WithEvents myOlExp As Outlook.Explorer

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Initialize_handler
End Sub

Public Sub Initialize_handler()
    Set objInspectors = Application.Inspectors
    Set myOlExp = Application.ActiveExplorer
End Sub

Private Sub objInspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Inspector)
    If Inspector.CurrentItem.Class = olMail Then
        Set objMailItem = Inspector.CurrentItem
        If objMailItem.Sent = False Then
            Call SetFromAddress(objMailItem)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

' Enable Outlook 2013/2016/2019/365 Reading Pane Reply
Private Sub myOlExp_InlineResponse(ByVal objItem As Object)
    Call SetFromAddress(objMailItem)
End Sub

Public Sub SetFromAddress(oMail As Outlook.MailItem)
    ' Set your preferred default From address below.
    ' Exchange permissions determine if it is actually stamped as "Sent On                 Behalf Of" or "Sent As".
    ' The address is not properly updated for the InlineResponse feature in Outlook 2013/2016/365. This is only a visual bug.
    If Not oMail.SendUsingAccount Is Nothing Then
        If oMail.SendUsingAccount.DisplayName = "default-address@domain" Then ' Default send address to be replaced.
            oMail.SentOnBehalfOfName = "desired-address@domain" ' Desired send address (must have delegate permission or be an alias).
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```